# Fade out custom path

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to fade out a custom path in an `axis` environment. So far, I am using the `nfold` library to create a new path with a defined offset and then fill the area between two neighboring paths.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{offset/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfgetpath\tikz@temp\pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty\pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}},
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[
ymode=log, 
xmin=0, xmax=200, 
ymin=1, ymax=10000,
grid=both,
]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\nsteps}{50}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\depth}{5}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,\nsteps}{
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\offsetA}{-\depth/\nsteps*#1}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\offsetB}{-\depth/\nsteps*(#1-1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\opa}{#1/\nsteps}

\path[save path=\mypath](52,10000) .. controls (198,207) .. (199,5) -- (159,5) .. controls (159,166) .. (50,5371) -- cycle;

\edef\tmp{
\noexpand\path[use path=\noexpand\mypath, offset=\offsetA, save path=\noexpand\mypathA];
\noexpand\path[use path=\noexpand\mypath, offset=\offsetB, save path=\noexpand\mypathB];
\noexpand\fill[even odd rule, use path=\noexpand\mypathA \noexpand\mypathB, opacity=\opa];}
\tmp
}

\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:52,7000);
\coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:50,10);
\end{axis}
\spy [blue, size=2.5cm] on (spypoint)
   in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the result is not too satisfactory, since there are small white spaces between each segment of the fade out area. Do you have any suggestions on how to get that better?
[image: MWE]

Comment: These tiny white segments are the result of the rendering, I'd assume.

Comment: Sorry, what am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Areas touching will be rendered with artefacts depending on viewer and zoom level. It comes from rounding and antialiasing. Instead of making the areas touch, just let them overlap with suitable opacity.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{offset/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfgetpath\tikz@temp\pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty\pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}},
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[
ymode=log, 
xmin=0, xmax=200, 
ymin=1, ymax=10000,
grid=both,
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nsteps}{50}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\depth}{5}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {\nsteps,...,1}{
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\offsetA}{-\depth}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\offsetB}{-\depth/\nsteps*(#1-1)}
\path[save path=\mypath](52,10000) .. controls (198,207) .. (199,5) -- (159,5) .. controls (159,166) .. (50,5371) -- cycle;
\edef\tmp{
\noexpand\path[use path=\noexpand\mypath, offset=\offsetA, save path=\noexpand\mypathA];
\noexpand\path[use path=\noexpand\mypath, offset=\offsetB, save path=\noexpand\mypathB];
\noexpand\fill[even odd rule, use path=\noexpand\mypathA \noexpand\mypathB, opacity=2/\nsteps];}
\tmp
}
\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:52,7000);
\coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:50,10);
\end{axis}
\spy [blue, size=2.5cm] on (spypoint) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with an area surrounded by a fading line]
[image: Zoom on corner of faded line]